# Paging in nested repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a nested repeater with 3 repeaters. This is how my data looks like:

**Refereed Journal Articles**

*In Press*

- Endorsement of the indigenous label
- Ethnic group stereotypes in New Zealand
- House Assets and Well-Being

*2012*

- Corporate Governance After the Global Financial Crisis
- Consuming Spirituality and the Spirituality of Consuming Media Narratives

**Books**

*2003*

- Endorsement of the indigenous label
- Ethnic group stereotypes in New Zealand
- House Assets and Well-Being

*2000*

- Corporate Governance After the Global Financial Crisis
- Consuming Spirituality and the Spirituality of Consuming Media Narratives

I am able to pull out the data into nested repeater. However, I am facing issue of how to put the paging in nested repeater as I use `ItemDataBound` events to populate the data in repeaters.

Answer (score 0):

To add support for paging in repeaters, you should use a `PagedDataSource`

Check it out [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx)